# undefined method `variant' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Quiero subir fotos para un articulo con lo cual tengo activado Active Storage e instalado tres gemas mini_magick y image_processing. También tengo en el modelo de article dos métodos encargados de hacer una redimensión de la foto, también tengo la relación con las fotos

```rb
def photo_as_thumbnail(photo)
    photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [300, 300]).processed
end
def photo_as_icon(photo)
    photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed
end
```

En el controlador añadí en los parámetros las fotos

```rb
private
    def product_params
        params.require(:article).permit(:name, :description, :price, photos: [])
    end
```

Para visualizar las fotos en la vista uso lo siguiente:

```rb
<% @product.photos.each do |photo| %>
    <%= link_to image_tag(@product.photo_as_thumbnail(photo)), photo %>
<% end %>
```

A la hora de listar los artículos y crearlos esta dando el siguiente error:

```
undefined method `variant' for nil:NilClass  
photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed  

def photo_as_icon(photo)  
    photo.variant(resize_to_limit: [50, 50]).processed  
end
```

Pero a la hora de editar un articulo no da ningún error y puedo subir y visualizar las imágenes así como guardar las modificaciones que hago en los diferentes campos

Comment: Creo que no has puesto el código revelante a tu error. El error menciona `photo_as_icon`, sin embargo tu codigo de la vista usa `photo_as_thumbnail`. ¿por que no mejor agregas el error entero a tu pregunta?, aparte del código donde llamas a `photo_as_icon`. De todas formas, como dice en el error estás pasando una foto con valor nulo al método, por eso falla.

Comment: @Alter Lagos El problema viene dado por no usar una condición para saber si un articulo tiene fotos, el estar llamando a ```photo_as_icon``` o a ```photo_as_thumbnail``` en no afectaba. Puedes consultar en https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75708799/undefined-method-variant-for-nilnilclass donde deje la misma pregunta en ingles

Comment: En product_params, estás seguro que debes colocar photos: [] en permit?.  Creo que debe ser :photos.